# Combine a list of dictionaries ; specific use case

Tags: python, django, dictionary

How do i combine this specific list of dictionaries i got from django query using values ? :

```
alist=[{"id":4,"name":"joseph","movie":3},{"id":6,"name":"kiley","movie":8}, {"id":4,"name":"joseph","movie":9},{"id":6,"name":"kiley","movie":17}]
```

I want to have :

```
anewlist=[{"id":4,"name":"joseph","movies":[3,9]},{"id":6,"name":"kiley","movies":[8,17]}
```

I know how to do it using iteritems , but i want a more generic way without using loops...

Comment: what is wrong with iteritems? I don't think you can do this without any loops...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using comprehensions only

```
result = [
    {
        'id': id,
        'name': next(x['name'] for x in d if x['id'] == id),
        'movies': [x['movie']  for x in d if x['id'] == id]
    }
    for id in set(x['id'] for x in d)]
```

but I highly doubt this would be more efficient or readable than a simple loop. KISS!